# Compiling against a newer version of glib?

Tags: gcc, packaging, glib

I'm working on a piece of software that needs to compile against a very modern version of glib, but also needs to run on Ubuntu 11.10 (which doesn't come with that version). My first thought was to just backport and replace glib, since the versions are theoretically compatible, but it causes some problems (most noticably with Unity not working right).

I know that the obvious solution is to use Ubuntu 12.04, but I don't have that option right now (working on it though).

Is there any sane way to handle this? Right now I'm looking at just compiling glib, `tar`ing it, and then manually setting `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Unfortunately, I don't think I can't even package the compiled library because glib isn't very specific about its version (it's just `glib-2.0.so`).

Is the `tar` method the best I can do in this situation?

Comment: Have a look at [this discussion about rpath](http://blog.flameeyes.eu/2010/06/the-why-and-how-of-rpath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest installing the new version of glib under `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/lib64` and then utilizing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, like you mentioned above.

In fact that appears to be the default location.  From the output of `./configure --help` in glib-2.33.8:

```
By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.
```

See [this Ubuntu Forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=912599) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had also similar problem, where I needed to compile the [ModemManager](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager), which needs a new version of GLib-2 on the OS where this version of `GLib-2` is not available via package manager (`Ubuntu 18.04`). I also did not want to break window manager (which I assumed has some dependencies on the `glib-2`).

The steps to compile with a newest version of GLib-2 which worked for me:

1. Compile `glib` from source (2022, June 2 it is hosted here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/). Recent versions use `meson` build system (so you need to install `meson` first if you do not have it), and the compilation goes:

```
meson build
cd build
meson compile
```

2. Install glib to some local folder using meson (different from the default location as it will overwrite existing GLib-2 files):

```
meson install --destdir /local/path/to/where/you/want/GLib-2/to/be/installed
```

I will use the `/local/path/to/where/you/want/GLib-2/to/be/installed` as `${install_dir}` below, but in the commands you need to substitute the `${install_dir}` with your path.

3. Modify the `*.pc` PACKAGE_CONFIG files of the custom installation of GLib-2, in the `${install_dir}/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` directory:

```
gio-2.0.pc
gio-unix-2.0.pc
glib-2.0.pc
gmodule-2.0.pc
gmodule-export-2.0.pc
gmodule-no-export-2.0.pc
gobject-2.0.pc
gthread-2.0.pc
```

Each of the file starts with a prefix:

```
prefix=/usr/local
```

which one needs to replace with the locally installed prefix:

```
prefix=${install_dir}/usr/local
```

Finally, invoke the configuration step of the ModemManager as follows:

```
PGK_CONFIG=${install_dir}/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig meson build
```

This way I was able to compile the [ModemManager](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager) with a newer version of GLib-2 than the OS provides.